# Flex child id not found in parent

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, canvas

I have a problem in my Flex 3 App.

```
< mx:Canvas id="detailsHeader" >    
    < mx:HBox id="contentContainer" >
       < mx:Canvas id="listContainer" />
    < mx:HBox />
< mx:Canvas />
```

I cant access the "contentContainer" dynamicly by code. 
Even if its created, visible, clickable and working.

`detailsHeader.hasOwnProperty("contentContainer") == false
    detailsHeader["contentContainer"] == fail(error) 
    detailsHeader.getChildByName("contentContainer") == null`

(ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property contentContainer not found on mx.containers.Canvas and there is no default value.)

I just dont get it. 
Iam open for each hint.

Comment: Example: "contentContair.visible"(as access) doesn't work for you? why do you want to access through the parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the other answers aren't telling you, is **why** your code doesn't work.

When you give an element an ID, the generated ActionScript code will be a variable/property at the class level. And I mean not the class that is being used as a container, but the class you're using the element in.

For example:

```
<!-- MyGroup.mxml -->
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <s:VGroup id="first">
        <s:Rect id="second"/>
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Group>
```

`first` will be a *property* of `MyGroup`, as will `second`. `second` is not a *property* of `first`, it is a *child* of it.

When you think about it, it makes perfect sense: suppose I would rely on `second` being a property of `first`. When I decide I no longer need `first` (it's just a layout class after all) and I remove it, all my code that is referring to `second` simply breaks, because it can no longer be accessed in the same way.
However if `second` is a property of `MyGroup` you can simply remove `first` and all your code relating to `second` keeps working as if nothing happened.

So as a conslusion, though the answers referring to `getChildByName` are technically correct, from a maintenance point of view I reckon you should not code that way.

Comment: Yes. I dont like the way the app is constructed too. 
It´s legacy, not my own. 

And it makes absolute sense. I just forgot that mxml placing all childs into the main definition. 
Thanks for the hint. I usually use such functions recursivly to debug native AS3 DisplayTrees. 

Regards

Comment: @Akirage There's an app for that ;) Check out [fxSpy](https://github.com/doublefx/fxSpy) or [KapInspect](http://lab.kapit.fr/default/kap-inspect/)

Answer (score 0):

If you adjust your mxml code to:

```
< mx:Canvas id="detailsHeader" >    
    < mx:HBox id="contentContainer" name="contentContainerName">
       < mx:Canvas id="listContainer" />
    < mx:HBox />
< mx:Canvas />
```

Then "contentContainer" should be available by following call:

```
detailsHeader.getChildByName("contentContainerName");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Name" attribute to implement getChildByName, try not to do but objA objB keychain and child objects, then you can create dynamic logic explicitly you need depending on your development.

```
private function access():void
    {
        var objA:Object = detailsHeader.getChildByName("contentContainer");
        var objB:Object = contentContainer.getChildByName("listContainer");
    }



    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:Canvas id="detailsHeader">
    <mx:HBox id="contentContainer" name="contentContainer">
        <mx:Canvas id="listContainer" name="listContainer">

        </mx:Canvas>
    </mx:HBox>
</mx:Canvas>
```